# Creating URL subdomains

Tags: dns, subdomain, django-urls

How are sites like bandcamp, blogger, etc creating these custom url with subdomains

example:

http://themidwestbreaking.bandcamp.com/

normally you have to add to your A-RECORDS in your DNS, but I am pretty sure they are not doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild card dns. There is a subdomain set up as `*`. You have to set up your webserver to accept *.yourdomain.com, then you can extract the subdomain from the URL and process however you want.